# How to import multiple fragments of file labled with the same label?

Tags: input, catchfile

I want to make include of labled part of file. I need something like [catchfilebetweentags](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/catchfilebetweentags/) but with the support  of multiple usage of the same lable. Catchfilebetweentags include just the first occurrence of lable.

Example:

File1.tex

```
    ...
    %<*tag>
    Some text I need
    %</tag>
    Some text I don't need
    %<*tag>
    Another text I need
    %</tag>
    ...
```

File2.tex

```
    ...
    \ExecuteMetaData [File1.tex]{tag}
    ...
```

This code produces:

```
    Some text I need
```

Comment: I think touhamis answer to my question should be adaptable to this case also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297389/import-several-parts-of-file-at-once/