# Figure problem with catchfilebetweentags

Tags: floats, errors, input, import, catchfile

This question is a follow up and based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297389/import-several-parts-of-file-at-once/297410#297410) by [touhami](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/71471/touhami)

---

---

### Situation

I would like to create an excerpt from a script that I have TeX'ed as a compendium of the most important statements (theorems & definitions).

There is a main-file importing chapterfiles with content. Additionally a summary-file ought to import some important parts. This is achieved with touhamis answer. But it should allow to include some and exclude some other figures, which leads to my problem...

### Question

## **How to import all tagged parts of a file with figures?**

(while keeping the numbering)

This means some figures are important and should be included, whilst others are not and have to be excluded (see MWE).

### MWE

file.tex

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\newenvironment{mtexclude}{}{}
\begin{document}
First bla bla
%<*tag>
\section{Foo}
\subsection{Foo bar}
I need this

\begin{mtexclude}% begin of part to skiped
    \section{Baz}
    \subsection{Baz bar}
    no need for this

    \begin{figure}[h] %this figure is the problem
        \fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{\center some picture...}}
    \end{figure}
\end{mtexclude}%   end

\section{End}
\subsection{End bar}
and need this \dots 

\begin{figure}[h] %this figure is ok
    \fbox{\parbox{\textwidth}{\center some other picture...}}
\end{figure}

\begin{mtexclude}% begin of part to skiped
    %no problems here
    \section{Baz 2}
    \subsection{Baz bar 2}
    another part to be skiped
\end{mtexclude}%   end

The end
%</tag>
Last bla bla
\end{document}
```

newfile.tex

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\newtoks\temptoken
\newbox\mtbox
\newenvironment{mtexclude}{\setbox\mtbox\vbox\bgroup}{\egroup}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{tag}
\the\temptoken

\end{document}
```

Comment: But there is no numbering for figures here?

Comment: Well figures not necessarily need a numbering but if a solution could include those also (and keeping that one also the same) it was preferable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to replace `mtexclude` definition

```
\newenvironment{mtexclude}{\setbox\mtbox\vbox\bgroup}{\egroup}
```

with

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mtexclude}{%
\setbox\mtbox\vbox\bgroup%
\def\@float##1{\def\@captype{##1}}%
\let\end@float\relax%
}{\egroup}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Excellent! Fixed the issue. It should be noted that this code replaces merely the old `
\newenvironment{mtexclude}{\setbox\mtbox\vbox\bgroup}{\egroup}` so one needs to keep the `\newtoks\temptoken
\newbox\mtbox`. This was not clear to me as a beginner.

Comment: @hillbilly sorry for that.

Comment: I found some other small problem that you might be the right person for. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354655/missing-spaces-when-importing-parts-of-other-file