# Missing spaces when importing parts of other file

Tags: spacing, input, import, catchfile

This question is a follow up and based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297389/import-several-parts-of-file-at-once) question (using an altered MWE from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298651/figure-problem-with-catchfilebetweentags) answer)

---

---

**Situation**

I am importing several parts of a file into another one (a summary-excerpt). This is done using the method described by touhami in the two linked questions.

**Question**

### Why do the spaces behind lines go missing, if and only if there is no subsequent comment `%...` ? And how to fix that ?

Obviously one could not use line breaks in code. Though for readabilities sake I'd prefer to have such without the need to add `%`all over the place.

---

**MWE** (compare linked posts)

*file.tex*

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{mtexclude}{}{}
\begin{document}
    First bla bla
    %<*tag>
    \section{Foo}
    \subsection{Foo bar}
    I need this % here is a space at end of line with comment afterwards
    certain text \textbf{``no more space!''}, 
    plus another one: \textbf{``without comments''}. 
    %
    But space goes missing.
    %note the space at the end of line 16 and 17 WITHOUT anything behind

    \begin{mtexclude}% begin of part to skiped
        \section{Baz}
        \subsection{Baz bar}
        no need for this
    \end{mtexclude}%   end

    \section{End}
    \subsection{End bar}
    and need this \dots 

    \begin{mtexclude}% begin of part to skiped
        %no problems here
        \section{Baz 2}
        \subsection{Baz bar 2}
        another part to be skiped
    \end{mtexclude}%   end

    The end
    %</tag>
    Last bla bla
\end{document}
```

*newfile.tex*

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\newtoks\temptoken
\newbox\mtbox
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mtexclude}{%
    \setbox\mtbox\vbox\bgroup%
    \def\@float##1{\def\@captype{##1}}%
    \let\end@float\relax%
}{\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{tag}
\the\temptoken

\end{document}
```

here are the results:
*file.tex*
[image: file.tex]
*newfile.tex*
[image: newfile.tex]

Comment: unrelated but as you see in the images that you post, you should not use `"` in latex input, use `\`\` ` and `''`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am sorry for such bad MWE. Usually I do use a custom command `\quotes{text}`, but by an oversight I have forgotten to do so here.

Comment: no harm done, it doesn't affect the question in any way, I just thought it worth mentioning:-)

Comment: it seems to be a bug.

Comment: @touhami hmm any way to fix this / where can we ask the developer of `catchfilebetweentags` about it ? (Or is there just the [email](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/catchfilebetweentags/catchfilebetweentags.pdf "on the left side of page one") ?)

Comment: you can try `\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\CatchFBT@Fin@l}{\endlinechar\m@ne}{}{}{}
\makeatother`

Comment: Terrific! It does fix the problem (I inserted the code just after the `catchfilebetweentags`- block)!

Comment: @touhami please add this as an answer, st. I can accept it. (maybe add the info on how to best incorporate the solution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one can fix this by adding

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\CatchFBT@Fin@l}{\endlinechar\m@ne}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}

\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\CatchFBT@Fin@l}{\endlinechar\m@ne}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\newtoks\temptoken
\newbox\mtbox
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mtexclude}{%
    \setbox\mtbox\vbox\bgroup%
    \def\@float##1{\def\@captype{##1}}%
    \let\end@float\relax%
}{\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{tag}
\the\temptoken

\end{document}
```

Comment: once again there has been an error with `\marginpar{}` that I am unable to track down. If you happen to have time, I suppose you're expertise with this chain of questions would be invaluable. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/424247/74942

Comment: @gr4nt3d will try tomorow