# Excluded `\marginpar{}` imported into another file fails to compile

Tags: input, marginpar, catchfile

This is another follow up question based on [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297389/import-several-parts-of-file-at-once) (using an altered MWE from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355027/74942) answer)

---

---

**Situation**

I am importing several parts of a file into another one (a summary-excerpt). This is done using the method described by touhami in the two linked questions.

**Question**

### How to use `\marginpar{}` with this exclude approach?

When I try to compile a file loading another one which contains a `\marginpar{}` inside an excluded part it fails.
Compare MWE: `newfile.tex` fails due to the `\begin{mtexclude} \marginpar{...} \end{mtexclude}` in `file.tex`.

---

**MWE** (compare linked posts)

*file.tex*

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\newenvironment{mtexclude}{}{}
\begin{document}
    First bla bla
    %<*tag>
    \section{Foo}
    \begin{mtexclude}% begin of part to skiped
        this works just fine
    \end{mtexclude}%   end
    works fine aswell
    \begin{mtexclude}% this exclude does not work
        this works only in the main ``file.tex''
        \marginpar{
        this causes the error in compilation of newfile.tex
        }
    \end{mtexclude}

    The end
    %</tag>
    Last bla bla
\end{document}
```

*newfile.tex*

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\newtoks\temptoken
\newbox\mtbox
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mtexclude}{%
    \setbox\mtbox\vbox\bgroup%
    \def\@float##1{\def\@captype{##1}}%
    \let\end@float\relax%
}{\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{tag}
\the\temptoken

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redefine `\marginpar` to do nothing (in the same way of figure and table) so we need to do

```
\newenvironment{mtexclude}{%
    \setbox\mtbox\vbox\bgroup%
    \def\marginpar{}%
    \def\@float##1{\def\@captype{##1}}%
    \let\end@float\relax%
}{\egroup}
```

---

**Note** be careful that inside `mtexclude` counters style work try with a `\section{foo}` inside `mtexclude` and `\section{bar}` outside it.

---

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{catchfilebetweentags}
\newtoks\temptoken
\newbox\mtbox
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mtexclude}{%
    \setbox\mtbox\vbox\bgroup%
    \def\marginpar{}%
    \def\@float##1{\def\@captype{##1}}%
    \let\end@float\relax%
}{\egroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\CatchFileBetweenTags\temptoken{file}{tag}
\the\temptoken

\end{document}
```

Comment: works splendidly! I am beginning to understand the scheme behind. Just reset everything to nothing inside the exclude environment. Though, I don't quite get the note (it might be addressed to readers unfamiliar with the first problem). The fact, that counters are still incremented is desirable; it was one important point of the first question in this row.

Comment: that's right, the two points